# Android Beam sound plays even though NFC is disabled

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

In our app we have a specific activity that the user is supposed to go to transmit some data that they enter on another screen.

I use this meta attribute in the manifest file to disable nfc in all activities

`<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.disable_beam_default" android:value="true" />`

And in `onPause()` of the transmit activity I call this:

`mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, this);`

However once I navigate away from the transmit activity, the other activities all vibrate and play the Beam sound but don't bring up the touch to beam view.

Is this something that anyone else has encountered? Is there something else that I need to do to prevent the other activities from vibrating and playing the Beam sound?

Comment: ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, sorry, we just ignored it, and decided it wasn't that much of an issue